# Куда девается оперативная память на Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Куда девается оперативная память на Windows?
Всего 8 ГБ оперативной памяти, однако как видно на скрине показывает, что занято 42% при том, что задействовано всего 850.
На линуксе у меня такой проблемы нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В системные приложения, которые вы на скриншоте не показали, очевидно

Comment: Загрузите ProcessExplorer с сайта Microsoft и просмотрите использование ресурсов с его помощью. Получите гораздо больше информации.

Comment: Видео не встроенное? Если да, то часть системной RAM откусывается на встроенный видеоадаптер.

Answer (score 0):

На скриншоте отображен общий ПРОЦЕНТ использование оперативной памяти системой, а КОЛИЧЕСТВО оперативной памяти относится к процессам запущенными от имени пользователя, помимо которых в системе работают сервисы, которые также используют оперативную память, но при этом запускаются не от имени пользователя.